# Window Graphic error using FLTK in ppp2 example of stroustrup

Tags: c++, window, fltk

I got this error:

> C2664 'void Graph_lib::Widget::attach(Window &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Graph_lib::Window' to 'Window &'

Here is some Window.h code

```
namespace Graph_lib {

class Shape;    // "forward declare" Shape
class Widget;

class Window : public Fl_Window {

....
```

and Window.cpp code, where the error occured

```
namespace Graph_lib {

....

void Window::attach(Widget& w)
{
    begin();            // FTLK: begin attaching new Fl_Wigets to this window

    **// I got error from this function**
    w.attach(*this);    // let the Widget create its Fl_Wigits
    end();              // FTLK: stop attaching new Fl_Wigets to this window
}

....
```

and GUI.h code, which has Widget class

```
namespace Graph_lib {

....

class Widget {

....

virtual void attach(Window&) = 0;

....
```

I tried to cast and to make a variable, but it's all same.

```
Window& win = *this;
Graph_lib::Window& win = *this;
w.attach(static_cast<Window&>(*this));
w.attach(dynamic_cast<Window&>(*this));
```

What do I do?

Comment: Looks like there is a global namespace class called Window defined somewhere.    Try qualifying all your Window with the Graph_lib namespace.

Comment: Could you post a minimum verifiable example.

Comment: Thank you, cup,  for your attention. I fixed it by overwriting files with someone uploaded from another site. And it works.